# add Incremented Number value to array based on common string values

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

What i'm trying to accomplish is trying to compare two strings in an array and output the number of occurances for each into a new array. I.E. Given a set constant Array of test0,test1,test2, and another array of test1,test1,test2 I want to search through the array to give a desired output of 0,2,1.

This is my code thus far but I am still at a loss on how to accomplish this.

```
private function findVal(arr1: Array, arr2: Array): Array {
    var tempNum: Array = new Array();
    for (var i: int = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        for (var ii: int = 0; ii < arr2.length; ii++) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[ii]) {
                var num: int = 0;
                //not sure where to go forward from here
            }
        }
    }
    return tempNum;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code simply counts up the number of occurrences of a string, then stores that in the tempNum array, and when the searching through arr1 is complete, the tempNum array is returned to the caller.

```
private function findVal(arr1:Array, arr2:Array): Array {

    var tempNum:Array = new Array(arr1.length);

    for (var i:int = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        var num:int = 0;
        for (var j:int = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
            if (arr1[i] == arr2[j]) {
                num++;  // count up the number of occurrences as you iterate through arr2 and compare with arr1
            }
        }
        tempNum[i] = num; // store the number of occurrences of string at index i of arr1 that occurred in arr2
    }

    return(tempNum);
}
```